# Cordova + JavaScript + Visual Studio 2015 : Page movement

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

There are index.html & index.js file.

In my index.html, Pages are divided into two pages;
First page is MQTT_Connection page. And the other is MQTT_communication page.

If Button in the MQTT Connection page is clicked then move to the MQTT_communication Page.

I expect that if MQTT_connect button is clicked than MQTT_Communication will be opened in Application.

However, it is not worked!

I don't know why only MQTT_Connection page is opened !

How can i fix it?

```js
var connect = false;



var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function (id) {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
            $(document).on("pagebeforeload", function (ev) {
                $.mobile.activePage.attr('id') == 'MQTT_Connection';
            });

        }, false);
        var element = document.getElementById("MQTT_connect");
        element.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
            console.log("clicked");
            $(document).on("pageshow", '#MQTT_Communication', function (ev) {
                //$.mobile.activePage.attr('id') == 'MQTT_Communication';
            });

        });

    },
    append:function (id,s) {
        // it is just a string append function. Nothing to do with the MQTT functions
        var node = document.createElement("p");                 // Create a <li> node
        var textnode = document.createTextNode(s);         // Create a text node
        node.appendChild(textnode);                              // Append the text to <li>
        document.getElementById(id).appendChild(node);     // Append <li> to <ul> with id="myList"
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <!--
            Customize the content security policy in the meta tag below as needed. Add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src to enable inline JavaScript.
            For details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=617521
        -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <title>SmartFarmApp</title>

        <!-- SmartFarmApp references -->
        <link href="libs/ratchet/css/ratchet.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="libs/ratchet/css/ratchet-theme-ios.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Page-->
        <section id='MQTT_Connection' data-role='page'>
            <div data-role="header" class="header">
                <h1 id="app-title">Smart farm MQTT Connection</h1>
                <a href="/" class="ui-btn ui-btn-left ui-btn-corner-all ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-notext" rel="external">Home</a>
            </div>
            <div role="main" class="ui-content">
                <form>
                    <label for="url">Url:</label>
                    <input id="url" name="url" type="text" placeholder="eg . tcp://172.30.1.254" required />

                    <label for="port">Port:</label>
                    <input id="port" name="port" type="number" placeholder="eg . 10200" required />

                    <label for="username">User ID:</label>
                    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="username" required />

                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input id="password" name="password" type="text" placeholder="username" required />

                    <!--Checkbox-->
                    <label for="tls"><input id="tls" type="checkbox" name="tls" value="tls" />TLS</label>
                    <label for="ssl"><input id="ssl" type="checkbox" name="ssl" value="ssl" />SSL</label>

                    <!--<input type="checkbox" name="chk_info" value="CSS" checked="checked">CSS-->
                    <button id="MQTT_connect">Connect</button>
                    <button id="MQTT_disconnect" style="display:none">Disconnect</button>
                </form>
                <!--<footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                    <h4>Visual Studio Tools for Cordova Demo</h4>
                </footer>-->
            </div>
        </section>

        <!--Page-->
        <section id='MQTT_Communication' data-role='page'>
            <div data-role="header" class="header">
                <h1 id="app-title">Smart farm MQTT connectivity</h1>
                <a href="/" class="ui-btn ui-btn-left ui-btn-corner-all ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-notext" rel="external">Home</a>
            </div>

            <div role="main" class="ui-content">
                <form>
                    <div>
                        <h4>Subscribe</h4>                                           
                        <p>
                            <label for="topic_sub">Topic:</label>
                            <input id="topic_sub" name="topic_sub" type="text" placeholder="subscribe topic" required />
                        </p>
                        <button id="subscribe">Subscribe</button><button id="unsubscribe" style="display:none">Unsubscribe</button>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <h4>Publish</h4>
                        <p>
                            <label for="topic_pub">Topic:</label>
                            <input id="topic_pub" name="topic_pub" type="text" placeholder="publish topic" required />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="payload">Payload:</label>
                            <input id="payload" name="payload" type="text" placeholder="message" />
                        </p>
                        <button id="publish">Publish</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer id="footer" data-role="footer">
        </footer>
        <!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>

        <!-- Libs -->
        <script src="libs/flux/js/Flux.min.js"></script>
        <script src="libs/ratchet/js/ratchet.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <!-- App -->
        <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Had to tell without seeing any code!

Comment: i added my code!!